# My LIST of customers gets populated but will not display in my Foreach loop in Server Side Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, list, foreach, blazor

I'm in the process of learning Blazor.  I created a Customer class with CustomerID and CustomerName and I am able to added add test customers to my LIST of customers, but when I use the LIST (thecustomers) in a Foreach loop to display them I get an error "The name thecustomers does not appear in the current context."  Please have a look at the code. What as I doing wrong?

```
enter code here



@page "/displaycustomers"


@using System.Collections.Generic

@using CustomerBlazorServerApp.Data

<h3>Display Customers</h3>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>CustomerID</th>
            <th>Customer Name</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>


        @foreach (var acustomer in thecustomers)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>acustomer.CustomerID</td>
                <td>acustomer.CustomerName</td>

            </tr>
            }
    </tbody>
</table>



@code {

  //  protected virtual void OnInitialized ();
    protected override void OnInitialized()
        {

        List<Customer2> thecustomers = new List<Customer2>();

        new Customer2 { CustomerID = "123", CustomerName = "Any Company" };
        new Customer2 { CustomerID = "456", CustomerName = "Some Company" };

        thecustomers.Add(new Customer2 { CustomerID = "123", CustomerName = "Any Company" });
        thecustomers.Add(new Customer2 { CustomerID = "456", CustomerName = "Some Company" });


        }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
 List<Customer2> thecustomers = new List<Customer2>();
```

Needs to be moved outside of `OnInitialized`. When its declared inside of `OnInitialized` it's scope is only that function and can not be accessed outside of it.

Example:

```
@page "/"
@using System.Collections.Generic

<h3>Display Customers</h3>

<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>CustomerID</th>
        <th>Customer Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var acustomer in thecustomers)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>acustomer.CustomerID</td>
            <td>acustomer.CustomerName</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>


@code {
    List<Customer2> thecustomers = new List<Customer2>();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        thecustomers.Add(new Customer2 { CustomerID = "123", CustomerName = "Any Company" });
        thecustomers.Add(new Customer2 { CustomerID = "456", CustomerName = "Some Company" });
    }

    public class Customer2
    {
        public string CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Kyle stated move the list outside of the method. But also you will need to tell the renderer that `<td>acustomer.CustomerID</td>` are generated content.

TLDR: `<td>@acustomer.CustomerID</td>`

Btw, you don't need the `@using System.Collections.Generic`. It "imported" by default into razor components. Also common used imports should be defined in _imports.razor.cs file.